# Worst placing in the climber competition for the overall winner

Tags: cycling, tour-de-france

It is clear that the Tour de France is won in the mountains. (On a flat stage there usually are mass finishes, with the winner not able to make up much time.) Hence the overall winner should also be a reasonably good climber.

What was the *lowest placing* in the climber competition of any winner of the Tour de France Yellow Jersey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official Best Climber Competition started in 1933. There was an unofficial ranking from 1905 to 1932 by the magazine Auto, but I couln't find these data.

In 1966, **[Lucien Aimar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucien_Aimar)** (France) didn't even make it to the Best Climber Classification, scoring 0 points.

In 1987, **[Stephen Roche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Roche)** (Ireland) also scored 0 points.

<sub>Sources: Wikipedia, [bikeraceinfo.com](http://www.bikeraceinfo.com/), [the-sports.org](http://www.the-sports.org)</sub>

Comment: Not that I doubt you, but do you have a specific link that says Roche scored 0 points in the KOTM in 1987? It doesn't tally with my memory of that race (I watched almost every second), but I willingly concede that I might be wrong.

Comment: @TrueDub [french](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tour_de_France_1987), [english](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1987_Tour_de_France) Wikipedias, and [bikeraceinfo](http://www.bikeraceinfo.com/tdf/tdf1987.html) agreed he wasn't in the Top 5. Then [the-sports](http://www.the-sports.org/cycling-tour-de-france-results-1987-epr15654.html) gives the full list. Reports said Roche won time on time trials, then even he had decent places in climbing stages, he didn't score points (points are only for the few first on the top, not at the end of the stage) and Roche only won one stage that year.

Comment: Thank you for your full list link. I'm well aware of how the points were awarded. I just thought he'd scored at least one point somewhere - incorrectly.

Comment: I did find a raft of information on the tour de france site, in their history section, and I gathered data back to 1975. Unfortunately, up to 1997 only the top three point getters are listed on the site. (And of course definitions, methods and available points have been constantly adapted.)